# Heroku + Rails: NoMethodError (undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

My app is running perfectly locally, but I'm unable to bring it up after pushing to Heroku.

Here are the logs:

```
2014-04-27T21:56:42.590706+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 98.217.72.49 at 2014-04-27 21:56:42 +0000
2014-04-27T21:56:42.593370+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by FinancesController#index as HTML
2014-04-27T21:56:42.593370+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by FinancesController#index as HTML
2014-04-27T21:56:42.621915+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28ms
2014-04-27T21:56:42.621915+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28ms
2014-04-27T21:56:42.623629+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-27T21:56:42.623629+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass):
2014-04-27T21:56:42.623629+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/finances_controller.rb:103:in `retirementalgorithm'
```

I did a heroku rake db:migrate and even a heroku restart.

Comment: Can you share `retirementalgorithm` method from `finances_controller.rb`. It seems like on line number `103` you have called `something/other_thing` where `something is nil`. If you share the code then I can pin-point it.

Comment: @getcompanysponsored = Investment.where(user_id: current_user, investmenttype: ['401k','403b']).sum(:contribution)

Comment: Let's discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the chat session with OP,

The error was on below line:

```
 @companysponsored = (finance.salary / 12) * (@getcompanysponsored.to_f / 100)* (@getcompanymatchupto.to_f / 100)
```

`@getcompanymatchupto` was set AFTER this call. Hence, its value was nil above. Suggested to define `@getcompanymatchupto` before using it.